# How to mix shaders depending on the direction normals are facing?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

How to make a gradual transition between two shaders, depending on the normal of the surface against the angle of the view.

The use case is I want to make bubbles of a white, somewhat opaque, liquid. When passing through the center (from the camera) it will pass through minimal liquid so it is most transparent there. When a ray passes near the rim it will pass through maximum liquid and be most opaque there.

I will just mix a transparent and opaque material. If the normal faces the camera, select the transparent material. If the normal is perpendicular to the camera, select the opaque material.

I have tried fresnel but it is meant for items refracting light.

I have tried the normal node but can't get it to work. I think that if I just use this correctly, this is the right way.

I have tried taking the normal of the object, normalize it and dot-product with the camera normal (normalized). It gives the result below. It is in the right ballpark, but not correct. Nevermind that it is black.

[image: preview of material with dot-product mix shader factor]

If I reverse the shaders I will get something like a puff of smoke, gradually becoming transparent at the edges.

Comment: What's wrong with fresnal? Does it end up affecting the glass/refraction shader or something?

Comment: It's not gradual. It is abrupt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [*Layer weight*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Layer_Weight) node with the *Facing* value as a mix factor:

[image]

The *Layer weight* node gives a map based on the angle of the surface to the camera:

[image]

When used to mix a diffuse and a transparent shader:

[image]

## Blending:

The *Blend* value controls the blending between angles:

With a low *Blend* value:

[image]

With a high *Blend* value:

[image]

As mentioned by CharlesL you could further control the blending with a *Color Ramp* node:

[image]

[image]