# Cigarette smoke material with cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm doing a blender project with a cigarette smoke. I don't use smoke simulation, the smoke is just a mesh simulated with soft body. Here is the mesh:

[image]

I've made a cool texture with blender internal :
[image][image]

But now I want to recreate the same, or the closer possible, material in cycles. Can somebody help my I'm really new to cycle material.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mix shaders depending on the direction normals are facing?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5172/how-to-mix-shaders-depending-on-the-direction-normals-are-facing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want:
[image]

The **Color Ramp** will allow you to control/fine-tune the amount of transparency.